# Can't switch state of UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

I have to `UISwitches` in my application. At launch, they're both set to off and the second switch is disabled and should only be enabled when the first switch is aswell, meaning:

```
@IBAction func switchOneToggled(sender: UISwitch) {
    if switchOne.on {
        switchTwo.enabled = true
    }
    else {
        switchTWo.enabled = false
    }
}
```

My problem is, that when I enable `switchOne`, `switchTwo` gets enabled, but I can't toggle `switchTwo`'s on/off state by touching it.

Comment: The code you’ve shown should serve you what you are trying to do. May be there’s something else in the attributes inspector which is causing this not to work.

Comment: @Vakas I've changed nothing in the attributes inspector other than setting the default state to be off.

Comment: Because you are missing code for `switchTWo.on = YES/NO;` Write YES just below the enabled = true and NO below the enabed = false.

Comment: `YES/NO`you mean `True/False`?

Comment: Do you want to check the state of switch one when the view is loaded? And take a decision to enable switch or no?

Comment: This big fat test could just be rewritten in a more comprehensible way: `switchTwo.enabled = switchOne.on`

Comment: @Cyrille Yeah, I guess. However it doesn't fix my problem changing my code to this

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the switches. I had a similar problem and just deleted the switch and replaced it, and giving it the same connections that is had before. It must be a bug inside Xcode, since it should be able to turn on and off without any code.

Comment: This worked for me.  The only changes in the storyboard file between the new and old versions were the addition of an `autoresizingMask` and a `fixedFrame="YES"` attribute.  Perhaps one or the other of those prevented touch interactions.  An outlet reference also disappeared, so maybe there was something there.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func switchOneToggled(sender: UISwitch) {
  switchTwo.enabled = switchOne.on
}
```

do you maybe have `userinteractionenabled` set to `false` for `switchTwo`?

Comment: userinteraction is enabled as by default. I also tried to make it true when toggling the switch just in case, but still doesn't work.

Comment: is there maybe some other (transparent) view above the switch that prevents you from toggling its state? or is the `userinteractionenabled` property set to `false` for any of the switches ancestors?

Comment: There's no view on top of any of the switches and I haven't set `userInteractionEnabled`to `false` anywhere. I have no clues.

Comment: Wanna share the Project via Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your switchOneToggled is called when the Switch is tapped and the state of the switch is changed. You should check the state of Switch 1 and enable your Switch 2 in your viewDidLoad.

Comment: But then `switchTwo` will only be set once when the state of `switchOne` is checked in `viewDidLoad`. It has to be checked every time `switchOne` changed its on/off state and set accordingly.

Comment: No. It will be set once the view is loaded and will be checked again with your switchOneToggled whenever the switch changes its state.

Comment: Check your IBAction is wired to your switch.

Comment: It is, because I can see `switchTwo` getting enabled upon pressing `switchOne`.

Comment: You should implement your switchOneToggled with sender. Like if sender.on == true { .... } because that's the UISwitch